# regEx for URL's in text. Catching img URL's

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Mathew O'Rordon seems like a great guy who have written a great regEx to pick up URL's in a [text](http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without). It works almost flawless. :)

But I found out one problem: If there is a img-tag with a static URL this regEx also catch it, which it should not. I am not fluent on regEx and I do not know what to do with this so it does not catch img src-URL's.

Editor with the script:
http://jsbin.com/futuyobawo/edit?html,js,output

Try to paste this into the text and see what happends with the img-code:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg/200px-Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg">
```

The script:

```
$(function() {
   var urlRegEx = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/g;
   $('#target').html($('#source').html().replace(urlRegEx, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"));
});
```

Is there anyone who can see what I need to do to make this regEx exclude img src URL's? That might be the last bit for the ultimate URL-regEx. :)

Comment: the regex does nothing with the image: http://jsbin.com/huzerizuso/1/edit?html,js,output are you expecting something else?

Comment: Yes, it does do this: `<img src="<a href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg/200px-Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg'>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg/200px-Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg</a> ">` which really mess up the code. I want the regEx to not pick up URL's in img-tags.

Comment: One solution, may be (I am not good at regEx so I am guessing here), to look for if **="** before this regEx. If it does exist it should not pass by this regEx since URL's always have those characters before in HTML. I just do not know how to do it and if it is the right solution.

Comment: Try this content and the error on the img occur: `www.wikipedia.org http://www.wikipedia.org matt@google.com https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg/200px-Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg http://wikipedia.org .<br><br>
    
    <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Hej</a>
    
    <br><br>
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg/200px-Hermann_Hesse_2.jpg">`

Comment: That is not valid HTML at all. You can not write an `<a>` tag inside the `src` of the `<img>` tag. Why are you doing that? Probably is what you want something like `<a href="#path_to_img.jpg"><img src="img_thumbnail_or_whatever.jpg" alt="Click on me" /></a>`

Comment: It is the regEx that is rendering that, it is the exact problem, and that is why I am writing here! I know valid HTML. :)

Comment: why is there `replace(urlRegEx, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")` ? try like `replace(urlRegEx, "$1")`  http://jsbin.com/tibitivivu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your suggested solution above does not work and definitly do not save the IMG-tag. :) Go here: [http://jsbin.com/futuyobawo/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/futuyobawo/edit?html,js,output) In the right column (Output), check the broken image at the bottom. The image above is how I added the image to the content. The broken image is how it looks after the function with regEx exectuted.